# Environment for high availability and scalability of the application

Tags: websphere-liberty

A system administrator needs to set a new Liberty profile environment to support an application.
What should the administrator do to enable this environment for high availability and scalability of
the application?

A.
Define multiple server members in one collective controller.

B.
Define multiple servers in a cluster in one collective controller.

C.
Define multiple collective controllers within a Liberty collective.

D.
Define multiple server members in multiple collective controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“A Liberty server cluster is comprised of two or more Liberty profiles configured into a server cluster within a Liberty collective.”

The correct answer should be Define multiple servers in a cluster within a Liberty collective…but that answer doesn’t exist so it’s between B and C for me…

A collective member can be configured with multiple collective controller endpoints. A collective member only communicates with one collective controller at a time; however, a configuration with more than one collective controller endpoint provides failover and workload balancing.

It should B